# Discord Bot Post requests to Browser

Tags: python, discord.py, minecraft

I would like to create a bot that sends a request (post) via a command `/refresh` with certain information so where I say `/refresh tes`t and it then sends a POST with certain information that is given for the time being.

Like this

```
client_id=CLIENT_ID_HERE&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_HERE&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN_HERE&grant_type=refresh_token&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI_HERE
```

but don't know how.

Comment: Use an URL library like aiohttp?

Answer (score 2):

So I reread this now many times. If I understood it right now, you just want to post something to, for example https://example.com/post

If so, then use [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) and create a client session and post it.

```py
import aiohttp

#this in your command
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    await session.post(“https://example.org/post“, data={“foo”:”bar”})
```